# Форма сказуемого после подлежащих — однородных членов

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, сказуемые, однородные-члены

*Проверь, чтобы квитанции, выписки и всё остальное максимально **соответствовало** тому, что написано в регламенте.*

Форму поставил ту, что лучше всего слышится, но в правильности не уверен. В правилах нигде не видел, чтобы в постпозиции сказуемое согласовывалось с последним подлежащим из ряда однородных.

Answer (score 1):

У глагола сильное управление:

**СООТВЕТСТВОВАТЬ**,  нсв. чему. Быть, находиться в соответствии с чем-л., отвечать чему-л

Писать надо кратко, но при этом излагать нужную информацию полностью:

**Проверь, чтобы квитанции, выписки и остальные документы полностью соответствовали друг другу по датам...**

Comment: 1) По вашей просьбе дополнил предложение. 2) А если без изменения "всё остальное" на "остальные документы"? Сложность то как раз в этом. Хотелось бы решить эту сложность, а не избежать её:)

Comment: Спасибо за дополнение,  из него я делаю для себя вывод: нет полного предложения - отвечать не имеет смысла, только время терять. Теперь ответ на вопрос. На выбор ЕД.ЧИСЛА преимущественное влияние оказало местоименное сочетание "всё остальное", то есть сочетаемость с ближайшим подлежащим, выраженным двумя словами в форме ед. числа и, кроме того, имеющим обобщающее значение. Думаю, что градация признака здесь ни при чем, это не тот случай.

Answer (score 1):

**Проверь, чтобы квитанции, выписки и всё остальное максимально соответствовало...**

Уверен, что именно единственное число. Думаю, можно сослаться на §190 п. 4 у Рознеталя:

> 4. Сказуемое обычно согласуется с ближайшим подлежащим при градации (расположении слов с нарастанием их значения); нередко в этих случаях однородным подлежащим предшествуют повторяющиеся слова каждый, всякий, любой, никакой, ни один и др. Например: Все разнообразие, вся прелесть, вся красота жизни слагается из тени и света (Л. Толстой); Каждое слово, каждая фраза резко, определенно, рельефно выражает у него [Гоголя] мысль... (Белинский); ...Каждая встреча, каждая беседа вносила все большее отчуждение и глухую неприязнь в их отношения (Н. Островский); ...Отобрать наиболее значительное, чтобы каждый эпизод, каждая деталь несла свою нагрузку (Шолохов); Никакое убеждение, никакая угроза на него не действует; Ни одна описка, ни одна ошибка не должна оставаться незамеченной, но, к сожалению, остается. ([§190. Согласование сказуемого с однородными подлежащими](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_08))

Comment: А чему соответствовало, можно было дописать? Выбор надо делать  для полного текста предложения. И  еще: соответствовать максимально, что это значит? Максимально, но не полностью?

Comment: @Jasmin, Увы, те, кто задает вопросы, не хотят обременять нас (или утруждать себя) дополнительными подробностями. Разве я должен придумывать окончание фразы? Можно предположить, что все должно соответствовать неким стандартам, требованиям в масимально возможной степени.

Comment: Придумывать мы не должны, хотя часто этим занимаемся. Просто я не уверена, что выбор формы согласования не зависит от концовки текста.

Comment: В таком случае напишите это в комментарии к вопросу. Пусть Василий будет щедрее на подробности, тогда и ответы будут точнее.

Comment: Это да, но я уже всем говорю: сложно расставить запятые и выбрать согласование, если у меня только полпредложения.